# Is there a transcript of the Futurama Live Q&A available?

Tags: futurama, online-resources

The Futurama Live Q&A occurred at http://www.comedycentral.com/shows/futurama/live.  Is there a transcript available for this Q&A?  Either official or fan transcribed is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a transcript but I've uploaded the closed captions below as subtitles.

Frankly the translation (courtesy of youtube) is pretty crap but you should be able to get the gist;

http://pastebin.com/ra1R1HRP

http://pastebin.com/hn68u7YC